# Mysql php update function problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I create a php code for mysql to do the fallowing?

if active = 1 to do current amount + 2000

```
id,   eid,       amount,   apply 1,  apply 2,      apply 3,  active
1     1788       500        NULL        NULL        NULL      1
2     1956       1000       NULL        NULL        NULL      1
3     2035       1500       NULL        NULL        NULL      1
```

And the output to be like this nothing else to change.

```
id,   eid,       amount,   apply 1,  apply 2,      apply 3,  active
1     1788       2500       NULL        NULL        NULL      1
2     1956       3000       NULL        NULL        NULL      1
3     2035       3500       NULL        NULL        NULL      1
```

Thanks in front for people who will help

Comment: so you want the amount + 200? and your example dictates 500+200=2500? Whats going on?

Comment: Nicky: 200? Reads 2000 to me.

Comment: don't forget to tick the answer that helped you resolve your issue! :) hint hint!

Answer (score 2):

The SQL query is as follows:

```
UPDATE tablename SET amount=amount+2000 WHERE active=1;
```

How you execute this in PHP depends on which database driver you're using.

For example, using `mysqli`:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_init();
mysql_real_connect($link, $host, $username, $password, $db_name);
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE tablename SET amount=amount+2000 WHERE active=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $host = "host";
    $username= "username";
    $password= "password";
    $db_name= "db_name";
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $link);
    mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET amount=amount+2000 WHERE active=1");
?>
```